# how to add custom font name and font size in ajax html editor extendor?

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

how can i add "Segoe UI" font in Ajax html editor extendor? i searched lot and find the option to customize Editor only but not able customize Editor Extendor. could any one tell me how do overwrite HtmlEditorExtendor property to Add cutom font and font-size?
Thanks,
Saravanan

Comment: Look at the source on your generated page and see if the tags render with a CSS class.  Then you can control via CSS that way.  Otherwise, you could do it by id using CSS.

Answer (score 1):

You need to download ajaxcontroltoolkit sources from the codeplex site and tweak a bit **HtmlEditorExtenderBehavior.pre.js** file in Client/MicrosoftAjax.Extended project (this is a link to this file on codeplex: [HtmlEditorExtenderBehavior.pre.js](http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Client/MicrosoftAjax.Extended/HtmlEditorExtender/HtmlEditorExtenderBehavior.Pre.js) 
Add your font families and font sized to appropriate arrays in `_createButton` function.

After that, you can rebuild project and use custom AjaxControlToolkit dll